# pass a class and returning different class as return object of java generic method

Tags: java, generics

I have a class `MyApi` with a generic method `get()` as below.

```
public class MyApi {

    public <T> T get(Class<T> clazz) {
        // business logic to create and return instance of T
        return null;
    }

}
```

Which is good so far. But in a few cases, I have to pass a class and will get different class Object in return.

How can I make the same method as generic without introducing a new parameter to same method, for example:

```
public class MyApi {
    public <T, E> E get(Class<T> clazz1, Class<E> clazz2) {
        // business logic to create and return instance of E
        return null;
    }
}
```

Eg: To avoid joins on NoSQL I have a `Employee` class and its materialized view class `EmployeeByDepartment`. For above api I pass `EmployeeByDepartment` and expecting `Employee` object as a response.

Comment: Do `T` and `E` have something in common?

Comment: You want your `get` to take `Class<T>` and return `E`? What would define `E`?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific - either show the real code or describe the details better - why would you pass int `Class<T>` and why would you get `E` in return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you re-phrase your requirements, you want to *return* a generic type, but don't care about the parameter type.

This will allow `T` to be inferred:

```
public <T> T get(Class<?> clazz) {
    // business logic to create and return instance of T
    return null;
}
```

Using classes in your example, you could then code:

```
Employee employee = myApi.get(EmployeeByDepartment.class)
```

You'll probably need an unchecked cast inside the `get()` method, but so what.

Comment: Is there any chance we can specify the return type explicitly while calling the method itself without passing any extra parameter? language supports that?

Comment: @Pokum yes! call it like this: `myApi.<Employee>get(EmployeeByDepartment.class)`. It's called "explicit typing"

Answer (score 1):

Your method is trying to do too much, namely, it's trying to resolve the correct class, and then create an object based on that class.

Let's split this up into two methods, one for resolving the correct class, and one for instantiating the object itself.

First, we find the correct class to create:

```
private Class getCorrectClass(Class<?> clazz) {

    if(clazz.equals(someClass.class)){
        return someOtherClass.class;
    }
    // whatever business logic that
    // will return proper class
    return clazz;
}
```

Then, we create it:

```
public <T> T get(Class<?> clazz) {
    Class clazzy = getCorrectClass(clazz);
    // business logic to create and return instance of T
    return (T) clazzy.newInstance(); //or however you decide how to init it
}
```

Now, whenever you call get, it'll resolve the correct class, then proceed to initialize the proper object.

Comment: In same method I have some meta information service to resolve actual class. Then I instance ate the class. Am already doing it